# JQuery $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took [**this snippet**](http://jsfiddle.net/CY9cs/) and placed all the code in index.html file as you can see below, but no matter where I put the js, jquery it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.parallax {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
}
.water {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    left:0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
.water-layer1 {
    background-image: url(http://elikirk.com/demos/liquipel/images/water-layer-1.png);
}
.water-layer2 {
    background-image: url(http://elikirk.com/demos/liquipel/images/water-layer-2.png);
}
.water-layer3 {
    background-image: url(http://elikirk.com/demos/liquipel/images/water-layer-3.png);
}
.water-layer4 {
    background-image: url(http://elikirk.com/demos/liquipel/images/water-layer-4.png);
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parallax">
    <div class="water water-layer4"></div>
    <div class="water water-layer3"></div>
    <div class="water water-layer2"></div>
    <div class="water water-layer1"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConstant = .015;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if(currentX == '') currentX = e.pageX;
  var xdiff = e.pageX - currentX;
  currentX = e.pageX;
   if(currentY == '') currentY = e.pageY;
  var ydiff = e.pageY - currentY;
  currentY = e.pageY; 
  $('.parallax div').each(function(i, el) {
      var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstant);
      var movementy = (i + 1) * (ydiff * movementConstant);
      var newX = $(el).position().left + movement;
      var newY = $(el).position().top + movementy;
      $(el).css('left', newX + 'px');
      $(el).css('top', newY + 'px');
  });
});
});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The jQuery is being loaded well before the script.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Don't reference jquery twice

Comment: Just to be sure, are you opening your file in http:// or file:// ? In the second case  it can't work.

Comment: Double check the console to make sure that jQuery has loaded.

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ElliotM That was out of desperation. It didn't work with one. I just tried it and the same error

Comment: Worked. I guess `//ajax.` and `http://ajax.` are two completely different things

Comment: You are using the google api's jquey. and in the fiddle used jquery library so try `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` instead of your library. and include it once only.

Comment: @iOi the main issue is that `//` means, "use the same protocol as the main page". If you're loading the main page from a local file (`file://`) then of course that'll be a problem, because the `//` without `http:` will mean the browser would try a `file://` path.

Comment: This is a jsfiddle with your html/css/javascript and all is working.. http://jsfiddle.net/yBJWT/

Answer (score 2):

You have referenced JQuery two times. Remove one of them and add reference as mentioned below :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery lib is not loaded on your script.

replace

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: No, using // is good practice. He just need to open correctly the master file.

Comment: @dystroy: what do you mean by master file ?

Comment: @dystroy Actually he gave the right answer. It worked when I did `http://`

Comment: @iOi Of course it "works" but it's not the right answer. Read the link I gave to get why. If you deploy your file on a server, using a protocol independent scheme **is** the good practice.

Comment: @dystroy it's good practice but won't work so good if the page URL is `file:///C:index.html` or something.